# Need SQL for selecting rows until sum of a column reach a value where the last row will not consume value in full

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Hi there could be many similar implementation but one thing i'm not able to find with the other threads here. so a new qs.

The Table contains two columns.
BOX_ID and No_of_Chocolates.
Rows:

```
BOX_ID, No_of_Chocolates
1, 10
2, 5
3, 15
```

Expectation is SQL query should return based on my needed number of chocolates.

Case 1: Needed chocolate =5
SQL Result should be:

```
1, 5
```

(Meaning, I can get the 5 chocolates from the first box itself)

Case 2: Needed chocolate =10
SQL Result should be:

```
1, 10
```

Case 3: Needed chocolate =13
SQL Result should be:

```
1, 10
2, 3
```

(Meaning, I need to take all from Box-1 and 3 from Box-2)

Case 4: Needed chocolates = 22
SQL Result should be:

```
1, 10
2, 5
3, 7
```

Case 5:  Needed chocolates = 35
SQL Result should be:

```
1, 10
2, 5
3, 15
```

(even though 35 chocolates are not there, it should give all the available chocolates)

Edit:
Sorry if the the result is misunderstood... the result will not be concatenated by a Comma. it will be two columns as it is.

Comment: Do you also have the requirement that you want to do this using as few rows as possible?  If so, then it might really be a dynamic programming problem.

Comment: wonder if you can get it with only sql query, looks like there should be a function realizing this task, then use it at sql query at where clausule. 
For example: Function (should be pipelined) would return ids of rows that it chooses separated by ',' , and as an entry parameter you should give number of chocolates needed.
Then you could use it at where clause using:
Select ....
from
where id in (function_call(35)), when you need 35 chocolates.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for replying. 
No. I do not want to do it with as few rows as possible. I will have the table with values ordered by date.

Comment: Hi Bartoz, Sorry if the the result is misunderstood... the result will not be concatenated by a Comma. it will be two columns as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a window sum and filter by that:

```
select
    box_id,
    least(
        :wanted - total_no_of_chocolates, 
        no_of_chocolates
    ) no_of_chocolates
from (
    select
        t.*,
        coalesce(
                sum(no_of_chocolates) over(
                order by box_id
                rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
            ),
            0
        ) total_no_of_chocolates
    from mytable t
) t
where total_no_of_chocolates < :wanted
```

`wanted` represents the target number of chocolates.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7be082f7c4c549f71f3f1bb3f57db746)**:

Results with `:wanted = 10`:

```
BOX_ID | NO_OF_CHOCOLATES
-----: | ---------------:
     1 |               10
```

Results with `:wanted = 13`:

```
BOX_ID | NO_OF_CHOCOLATES
-----: | ---------------:
     1 |               10
     2 |                3
```

Results with `:wanted = 22`:

```
BOX_ID | NO_OF_CHOCOLATES
-----: | ---------------:
     1 |               10
     2 |                5
     3 |                7
```

Results with `:wanted = 35`:

```
BOX_ID | NO_OF_CHOCOLATES
-----: | ---------------:
     1 |               10
     2 |                5
     3 |               15
```

Answer (score 0):

GMB's solution is correct.  But I think there is a simpler way to express similar logic.

I would use a cumulative sum, but like this:

```
select b.box_id,
       least(:needed - sum_upto_box, no_of_chocolates) as from_this_box
from (select b.*,
             sum(no_of_chocolates) over (order by box_id) - no_of_chocolates as sum_upto_box
      from boxes b
     ) b
where sum_upto_box < :needed
```